# how can i sign a file in Qt using sha1 digest?

Tags: ruby, qt, openssl

I need to sign a file using QCA and qca-ossl in Qt.
the input is a private key and a zip file.
in ruby this can be done like this

```
@sig = @key.sign(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new, plain)
```

in Linux I can do this by with command:

```
openssl rsautl -sign -in file -inkey key.pem -out sig
```

Here the private key I got in qt by

```
QCA::PrivateKey seckey = QCA::KeyGenerator().createRSA(1024);
```

now I need to do the signing in qt

can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [QCA::PrivateKey::signMessage](http://delta.affinix.com/docs/qca/classQCA_1_1PrivateKey.html#abf1b6508812fdf8e3b0efc3c1deb7f5), [QCA::SignatureAlgorithm](http://delta.affinix.com/docs/qca/namespaceQCA.html#c368775aaad8054778f4199999f49ca6)
 and [QCA::MemoryRegion](http://delta.affinix.com/docs/qca/classQCA_1_1MemoryRegion.html)

I guess something like:

```
QByteArray signResult = seckey.signMessage(QCA::MemoryRegion(plain),
                                                     QCA::EMSA1_SHA1);
```

Comment: The signature is created using the RSA algorithm with the SHA-1 hash function. So that means there is no way i can do this?

Comment: Yes the idea of signature is to fold your data in some hash and than encrypt it with private key (sign data), so those who have public key will be able to decrypt it. I can't understand your question. What you think you can't do and how it related with signing message?